# Find string in data frame and store new values in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a script that takes a csv file which columns organisation and columns name are unknown. However I know that only one of the column contains some values in which the str 'rs' and 'del' appears.

I need to create an extra column (called 'Type') and store 'dbsnp' in the row where 'rs' was found and 'deletion' in the row where 'del' was found. If not str is found, leave this row in column type empty.

As example I provide this df:

```
Data = {'Number': ['Mukul', 'Rohan', 'Mayank', 
                  'Shubham', 'Aakash'], 
          
        'Location': ['Saharsanpur', 'MERrs', 'rsAdela', 
                     'aaaadelaa', 'aaa'], 
          
        'Pay': [25000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000]} 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
print(df)

 Name     Location    Pay
0    Mukul  Saharsanpur  25000
1    Rohan        MERrs  30000
2   Mayank      rsAdela  35000
3  Shubham    aaaadelaa  40000
4   Aakash          aaa  45000
```

I have been trying things like that

```
df["type"] = df["Name"].str.extract("rs")[0] 
# and then do some replace
```

But one of my problems is that I dont know non the name of the column neither the position.

Desire output

```
 Name     Location    Pay       type
0    Mukul  Saharsanpur  25000 dbsnp
1    Rohan        MERrs  30000 dbsnp
2   Mayank      rsAdela  35000 dbsnp
3  Shubham    aaaadelaa  40000 deletion
4   Aakash          aaa  450
```

The next for loop solve the problem of the unknown column but now I need to solve the issue of identify my str in the value.

How can I use str.contains("rs") in the if condition?

```
for index, row in df[:3].iterrows():
    for i in range(len(df.columns)): 
        if row[i] == 5:
            print(row.index[i])
```

Comment: did you try str.contains ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without the loop. Here's an approach. You can use applymap and search all the columns.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Number': ['Mukul', 'Rohan', 'Mayank', 
                  'Shubham', 'Aakash'], 
          
        'Location': ['Saharsanpur', 'MERrs', 'rsAdela', 
                     'aaaadelaa', 'aaa'], 
          
        'Pay': [25000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000]} 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['rs'] = df.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: 'rs' in x).any(1)
df['del'] = df.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: 'del' in x).any(1)

df['type']=''
df.loc[df['rs'] == True, 'type'] = 'dbsnp'
df.loc[df['del'] == True, 'type'] = 'deletion'

df = df.drop(columns=['rs','del'])
print (df)
```

Based on the data in the table, `rsAdela` has both `rs` and `del`. Since I am applying `rs` first and `del` second, the row is flagged for `deletion`. You can choose to swap the order to decide if you want to retain value as `dbsnp` or `deletion`.

The code processes all the columns irrespective of dtype.

The output of the above data is:

```
    Number     Location    Pay      type
0    Mukul  Saharsanpur  25000     dbsnp
1    Rohan        MERrs  30000     dbsnp
2   Mayank      rsAdela  35000  deletion
3  Shubham    aaaadelaa  40000  deletion
4   Aakash          aaa  45000
```

Comment: How can I close the question??

Comment: Dont worry about it. You marked the answer as correct. Thats what i meant. Glad I could help. applymap is the way to go here. There may be better ways. Will research and update if I find other ways without the use of apply

Answer (score 0):

This example can help you:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

inp = [{'c1':10, 'c2':100}, {'c1':11,'c2':110}, {'c1':12,'c2':120}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

df['newColumn'] = ""
yourCondition = True
for i in range(len(df)):
    # put your condition here
    #
    # if df['Name'].values[i].find("rs") != -1:
    #    df['newColumn'].values[i] = "Found!"
    # else:
    #    df['newColumn'].values[i] = "Not Found!"
    if (yourCondition):
        # now you can update what you want
        df['newColumn'].values[i] = random.randint(0,9)

print(df)
```

**output**

```
   c1   c2 newColumn
0  10  100         5
1  11  110         7
2  12  120         2
```

You can add a new column like this: `df['newColumn'] = ""` 
And iterate and dataframe like this: `for i in range(len(df)):`
And then you can have access to the element like this: `df['newColumn'].values[i]`

Comment: Thank for your help. In 'put your condition here', that is the key point of this question. I dont know how to get the name of the column where the string rs is.

Comment: I DONT know the name of the column, neither the position.

Answer (score 0):

you could use str.contains as @Joe Ferndz said:

```
# create filter based on your criteria
msk1 = df['Location'].str.contains('rs')
msk2 = df['Location'].str.contains('del')

# only make changes to those that fit the criteria
df.loc[msk1, 'Type'] = 'dbsnp'
df.loc[msk2, 'Type'] = 'deletion'

# if you wish to fill NaN with empty string
df['Type'] = df['Type'].fillna('')
```

Comment: AGAIN. I dont know the name and I dont know the position of the column that contain the  the values I am looking for. I just provided an example to make easier my explanation and to make easier the answers.

Comment: well. then i think you will need to add a for loop around the code for every column in order to find out whether certain column contains the value that you are looking for.

Comment: another possible way is to concat all str columns, and do str.contains;

Comment: I have added I think the for loop you mention. But now I dontr know how to identify the str in the value

Comment: It can be done without a for loop. The for loop is costly.

Comment: This also return a error. pandas dataframe dont use .str